# read an XML file in Java application?

Tags: java, xml

Read in an XML file in Java application?

```
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

I am getting an error:

`"Syntax error on token "getDocumentElement", Identifier expected after this token"`.

here is full code:

```
package SalesForce_Common;

import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class ReadDataFromXmlFile {

     File fXmlFile = new File("/Users/mkyong/staff.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
}}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Selenium, removed tags.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error means that your code isn't correct from the compiler point of view, so we need the full code snippet in order to help you.

Comment: As Etienne said you need to write code in a method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write code directly in a Java class. You need to wrap it in a method. In your case, it seems you want a `main`:

```
public class ReadDataFromXmlFile throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    File fXmlFile = new File("/Users/mkyong/staff.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");
    System.out.println("----------------------------");
  }

}
```